# Fastreport изменить цвет memo по щелчку на нем

Tags: delphi

По двойному щелчку меняю цвет TFrxMemoView:

```
procedure TfraMechSampleListSumReport.frxReportDblClickObject(Sender: TfrxView;
  Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; var Modified: Boolean);
var
  curMemo : TfrxMemoView;
  Sample: string;
begin
  if not(Sender is TfrxMemoView) then exit;

  curMemo := TfrxMemoView(Sender);

  curMemo.Color := clRed;

  exit;
end;
```

Цвет обновляется только после того как сверну и вновь открою окно очета. Как можно обновить окно отчета или Memo самому? Может есть другой способ изменить цвет по щелчку?

Answer (score 1):

после того как поменяли цвет - надо сделать перерисовку окна.

Comment: Это понятно - метод подскажите. Refresh и Repaint я не нашел.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте после `curMemo.Color := clRed;` сделать `curMemo.Update;` или `curMemo.Repaint;`
Что там есть у этого memo?